# Putting text next to the image css, seems not working

Tags: css

What am I doing wrong? :|

```
 <div id=Content>
                    <h1>Welcome to the Sophia Centre press</h1>
                    <h2>New Publications Avaible Soon</h2>

                    <div id=Malta>
                    <img src ="images/Malta.jpg" alt="Malta" class="book">
                    <p>Tore Lomsdalen</p>
                    <p><em>Sky and Purpose in Prehistoric Malta: Sun, Moon, and Stars at the Temples of Mnajdra.</p></em>
                    </div>

                    <div id=Greene>
                    <img src="images/Greene.png" alt="Greene" class="book">
                    <p>Liz Greene</p>
                    <p><em>Magi and Maggidim: The Kabbalah in British Occultism 1860-1940.</em></p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

and the css

```css
h1{
 
        padding: 1em;
}
h2{
        padding-left: 1cm;
        color: #FF9900;
}
 

p {
        clear: both;
        margin: 0% 0% 0% 20%;
}
 
 
.book{
float: left;
padding: 2em;
}
```

How it looks 1)
How it should be looking 2)

http://imgur.com/a/DqjnQ

I just want the **text** to be moved next to the images in content
halp

Comment: Please add your code to your question, no links. You'll have a better chance of having your question answered if you don't _"hide"_ the crucial parts from them.

Comment: @hungerstar okay, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the property `display: inline-block`.

`<img>` tags are naturally inline, and don't need it set, but since you are trying to inline your `<p>` tags, you'll need to set their container to `display:inline-block` to account for it.

Code changes:

```
        <div id=Malta>
            <img src ="images/Malta.jpg" alt="Malta" class="book">
            <div class="textContainer">
                <p>Tore Lomsdalen</p>
                <p><em>Sky and Purpose in Prehistoric Malta: Sun, Moon, and Stars at the Temples of Mnajdra.</p></em>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.textContainer {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: it seems working now although I still have the text next to the bottom of image, if I change anything now, it destroys whole content :F

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that :/ worked on my local page based on my interpretation of the question

Comment: Try adding to .textContainer `vertical-align:top` as well. It might do the trick.